# Graph wont show up

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jgraphx

I am very new with gui and java so I am just trying out some things. I have this small code similar to Hello World, and even though there are no errors, when i run it all I get in the console is: mxGraph version "2.1.1.0"
Any ideas what I did wrong? Thanks in advance

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent;
import com.mxgraph.view.mxGraph;


public class Design extends JFrame {

    public Design() {

        super("Test");

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(400, 320);
        f.setVisible(true);

        mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
        Object parent = graph.getDefaultParent();


        graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
        try
        {
            Object v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "hi", 20, 20, 80,
                    30);
            Object v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "bye", 240, 150,
                    80, 30);
            graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "Edge", v1, v2);
        }
        finally
        {
            graph.getModel().endUpdate();
        }

        mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph);
        add(graphComponent);

        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably seeing the output from the classloader. Add a `main` method to display the `JFrame` itself

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Design design = new Design();
            design.pack();
            design.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

You should see

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still get nothing

Comment: How are running the application? IDE? What version of Java?

Comment: Eclipse and java se 7